# Python datamodels

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a library to access an API. I have made one in C# and in Java allready, but now I am making one in Python. I use dictionary's for the data, but I run into a problem.

In C# and Java I use objects, so if a datamodel depends on another, I just make a new instance of the object and add it to the property. But python is a bit different.

I am needing nested dictionary's, that is not a real problem, the real problem is the amount of repeated code.

checkout_order (uses checkout, items and address) looks as follows (not completed yet):

```
checkout_order = {'id': None, 'status': None, 'dateTime': None,
              'checkout': {'id': None, 'amount': None, 'status': None, 'paymentUrl': None,
                           'setupUrl': None, 'returnUrl': None, 'billingAddress': {'name': None, 'line1': None,
                                                                                   'postCode': None, 'city': None,
                                                                                   'country': None}}, 'items': {},
```

I think you'll get the idea... Nested in nested, and I do not want to fill the origional dictionary with what needs to go inside this one.
So is there a shorter way of doing this, with less clutter and a bit more DRY? Because every nested dict exists somewhere else aswell...

Comment: "In C# and Java I use objects, ... But python is a bit different." You now that you can define classes and use objects in Python, too, right? If you need the data as a dictionary, you can still do `obj.__dict__`

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize dictionary from the list

```
dict.fromkeys([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `defaultdict`. Example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
checkout_order = defaultdict(lambda: None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I was looking for.

```
checkout = {'id': None, 'amount': None, 'status': None, 'paymentUrl': None,
        'setupUrl': None, 'returnUrl': None, 'billingAddress': {'name': None, 'line1': None,
                                                                'postCode': None, 'city': None,
                                                                'country': None}}
checkout_ = checkout
checkout_order = {'id': None, 'status': None, 'dateTime': None,
                  'checkout': [checkout_], 'items': {},
                  'billingAddress': {'name': None, 'line1': None,
                                     'postCode': None, 'city': None,
                                     'country': None}}
```

I need to splice more dicts in parts, but this is a huge difference. BTW, the checkout dict was allready there, but I did not show it in the question, because it was not relevant and would lead to clutter.

But thanks for the reactions and other solutions, I will look in to them ofcource and maybe switch to an other implementation.

Comment: Not sure what you intended to do with `checkout_ = checkout`, but note that this will _not_ create a copy of the dict, but just another reference to the same dict.

Comment: Oh, so if I fill checkout_, checkout will be filled aswell?

Comment: Exactly. `a = []; b = a; a += [1]; print(b) --> [1]`. If you want a copy, you can use `import copy; checkout_ = copy.deepcopy(checkout)`